# Solve system of equations $3|x|+2y=1, 2x-|y|=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

help with this system of equations
\begin{cases}
3|x|+2y=1 \\
2x-|y|=4 \\
\end{cases}
I have no idea.

Comment: Notice that if $x<0$, there is no solution to the 2nd equation, so you can drop the absolute values in the 1st equation.  Since $3x+2y<2x-|y|$ with $x\ge0$, $y<0$ so you can replace $|y|$ by $-y$ in the 2nd equation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Setting $x$ from second equation $(x=\frac 1 2 (|y|+4))$ 
and substituting the first equation, we get $$1.5 \big||y|+4\big|+2y=1.$$

For all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we get $||y|+4|=|y|+4$
and the equation can be written in the form $1.5 |y|+2y=-5$.

The solution to this equation is $y=-10$.

So the ultimate solution of our system of equations is $(x,y)=(7,-10)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You may want to look at the [MathJax formatting guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing symbols in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using $a>0\implies |a|=a, a<0\implies |a|=-a$, solve the four systems below and check compatibility:

$$++\begin{cases}
3x+2y=1 \\
2x-y=4 \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$-+\begin{cases}
-3x+2y=1 \\
2x-y=4 \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$+-\begin{cases}
3x+2y=1 \\
2x+y=4 \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$--\begin{cases}
-3x+2y=1 \\
2x+y=4 \\
\end{cases}
$$